# How to add value into a form before saving in Django

Tags: python, django

I want the user to fill some form, then add the user's id and user's branch(from another table, by releation) to add to the form data before saving it. the form has other fields like {type, serialno, model, date}, after it is submitted i want to add userid and branchid to that form value and submit it to database

This is my view.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX883.png)

I tried to overide the form data as you can see in the picture. But, it keeps showing me an error message of "TypeError"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with `form.save(commit=False)`, this method is used when you want to create or update a model instance using the data from a form but do not want to save it to the database immediately. This is particularly useful when you need to perform additional processing or validations before saving the data.

**Example:**

```py
if form.is_valid():
    user = request.user
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.sent_by = user
    instance.branch = Branch.objects.filter(code=user.first_name)
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Your answer was to the point and exactly what I wanted. You even made it easy for me to integrate it into my code, without adding any complexity. Cudos my friend

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can go two ways:

1. [Override save method for your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) and use save as the following:

> form.save(user=user, branch=branch)

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['type', 'serialno', 'model', 'date']

    def save(self, user, branch, commit=True):
        instance = super(YourForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = user
        instance.branch = branch

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance
```

2. As the .save() method creates an object of your Form class, you can you the .save(commit=False) method call, modify the user and branch for the created instance, and then call an actual save to the db.

```
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    
    instance.user = user
    instance.branch = branch
    
    instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Morning Semon hope you are well.

If it is any help I have a similer setup in my HR project over on my github page which you are more than welcome to if it helps.

The user fills in a form which is then transferred to a PDF.

In relation to the error without looking at all of your project I can only imagine its referring to the following:

Is your import correct for Branch ?
Is this how your model is named ?

Is code part of your model ?

If you can show me the full error message that would be great. Or DM me it.

At a guess very similar to Sashkins answer:

```
if form.is_valid():
   user = request.user
try:
    branch = Branch.objects.get(code=user.first_name)
except Branch.DoesNotExist as e:
    print(e)
    branch = None
    Add a redirect here if the branch is not found
if branch:
    form.cleaned_data['sent_by'] = user.id
    form.cleaned_data['branch_id'] = branch.id

# Save form
form_instance = form.save(commit=False)
form_instance.sent_by = user  
form_instance.branch = branch  
form_instance.save()

return redirect('andrewbyteforge')
```

Let me know if you have any problems.